# Compile C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw

I'm trying to compile C++ on Windows.
The command needed to compile on Linux is:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC `python -m pybind11 --includes` EO_functions_bipartite.cpp -o extremal_bi.so
```

I installed MinGW but when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
g++.exe: error: python: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: pybind11: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-m'
g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '--includes EO_functions_bipartite.cpp'
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: There are tools and libraries you haven't installed, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have python in your path.

The backtick escape thing that embeds the `python -m pybind11 --includes` command within the g++ doesn't work on cmd.exe in Windows.

Run the `python -m pybind11 --includes` command on its own line in the cmd shell.  Take the output of that command and substitute in into the g++ command.  It should be a bunch of `-I` include params.

So if the output of the python command is this:

```
-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pybind11\include
```

Expand your g++ command to be this:

```
g++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -fPIC "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pybind11\include EO_functions_bipartite.cpp -o extremal_bi.so
```

Notice the quotes I put around the first include directory because it has a space in its path.

Comment: This is what I get: -IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pybind11\include                                         What should I do now?

Comment: @Dario - answer updated to show you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to start on native Windows if you have a Linux background is to install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell with MinGW-w64. This will provide an actual `bash` that allows you to run commands almost exactly the same way as on Linux, including support for backticks like in the case of your issue.

Though I would always recommend using `$( ... )` instead of backticks, as this allows nesting.

Note that MinGW-w64 also exists on Windows to allow cross-building for Windows from Linux, but that may be a bit more difficult if you have never done any cross-building before.

Also `-shared ... -o extremal_bi.so` in your command should be replaced with `-shared ... -o extremal_bi.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libextremal_bi.dll.a` as `.so` files don't exist on Windows as Windows uses `.dll` files for shared libraries and the compiler uses `.dll.a` files as library objects for them.

Finally on Windows you need to tell the compiler or linker which symbols you will be exporting by either writing a `libextremal_bi.def` starting with the line `EXPORTS` followed all the symbols you want to be exported and include `-def libextremal_bi.def` in the link command, or using `__declspec(dllexport)`/`__declspec(dllimport)` when defining those symbols, which may be a bit complexer as it requires some conditional defines to determine if the code is being compiled for Windows and if it's during the actual build process of the shared library (`__declspec(dllexport)`) or code that uses it (`__declspec(dllimport)`). There is also another method to export all symbols, but that's a dirty method that may more easily cause symbol conflicts.